# alignment issues with floats after media query

Tags: html, css

I am very new to CSS and to practice my skills, I am attempting to make a page that has the layout of the following diagram:
[image: Ideal page layout]

So far I have managed to replicate this structure using floats after some research. I have applied a media query to the page so that at 600px all the elements are presented as block elements in a single row, text aligned to the center. However the issue is that, the blue and green elements from the above diagram align to the center with the text being in the middle of the images- however the red elements do not. I am unsure why this may be happing and can't seem to find the issue.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.column .title h1,
img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
}

.column .title img {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}

.column .title {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.column li,
a {
    font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.column .sub-content ul {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.context h1,
h2,
p {
    font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        clear: both;
        display: inline;
        margin-left: 200px;
    }

    .column .sub-content ul {
        clear: both;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

    .column .sub-content li {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="title">
                <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                <h1>Content 1</h1>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                    <h2>Content</h2>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                    <h2>Content</h2>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                    <h2>Content</h2>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                    <h2>Content</h2>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="title">
                <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                <h1>Content 2</h1>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                    <h2>Content</h2>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                    <h2>Content</h2>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                    <h2>Content</h2>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                    <h2>Content</h2>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="title">
                <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                <h1>Content 3</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-content">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Sub content 1</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Sub content 1</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Sub content 1</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="square.svg" width="50px" />
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any guidance towards the right direction is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Look up CSS grid and flexbox. If you are starting out CSS in 2021 and you're using `float` for layout, imo you are looking at the wrong resources...

Comment: You can do it with much ease with css flexboxes. Any specific reason to use floats?